# In Orbital Mechanics what is the quantity described below called?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, orbital-motion, conservation-laws, terminology

I seem to recall that $r^2 \dot{\theta}$ is a conserved quantity in orbital mechanics, which I just proved using the Euler-Lagrange equations. Namely via:

$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{m}{2} (\dot{r}^2+r^2 \dot{\theta}^2)+\frac{GMm}{r}$

$\frac{\partial{\mathcal{L}}}{\partial \theta}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\theta}}$

$\therefore 0=\frac{d}{dt} (r^2 \dot{\theta}) $

$\implies r^2 \dot{\theta}=C$

My question is, what is this quantity called as I can't seem to recall its name, but I think it does have a special name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$mr^2\dot\theta$ is the angular momentum, which is conserved. The quantity $r^2\dot\theta$ is conserved if $m$ is independent of time, but it doesn't have a name that I know of.

Comment: [Specific angular momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_relative_angular_momentum)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your calculation. Its $mr^2\dot\theta$ which is equal to a constant. This is the angular momentum which we know is conserved.

Comment: Since $ \mu r^2 \dot{\theta} $ is a constant of the orbit, and $M$ is constant, then $ r^2 \dot{\theta} $ is also a constant of the orbit.

Answer (score 0):

$ r^2 \dot{\theta} $ is known as the *[specific angular momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_relative_angular_momentum)*.

Also, the correct formula for the 2 body Lagrangian is actually:
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{\mu}{2} (\dot{r}^2+r^2 \dot{\theta}^2) + \frac{GMm}{r} = \frac{Mm}{M+m} \frac{\dot{r}^2+r^2 \dot{\theta}^2}{2} + \frac{GMm}{r} $$
where $ \mu = \frac{Mm}{M+m} $ is the reduced mass.